# Can not understand difference in behavior between : @EnableWebMvc and <annotation-driven />

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I was looking for annotation based approach for `<interceptors>` and then found the way [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors)

So I used it and its working, but there is a catch.

When I do;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
     ....
}
```

and there is no `<annotation-driven />` tag in servlet-context.xml then it works perfectly fine and url are intercepted and corressponding pre-post logic works as implemented in "WebApplicationConfig " -  my custom interceptor.

But if I remove `@EnableWebMvc` and add `<annotation-driven />` then logically speaking application does not work, meaning no url's are intercepted its like "WebApplicationConfig " class is not even there.

and off cource if I keep both `@EnableWebMvc` and `<annotation-driven />` then I get exception while deploying the application. :

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
    ..........
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver 

org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver()] threw exception;

 nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:

 org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$56a95502 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
```

So why url's are not intercepted , when I used `<annotation-driven />` instead of `@EnableWebMvc`

Also if I go with `@EnableWebMvc` and no `<annotation-driven />`, then using  `@EnableWebMvc` at place of declaring class WebApplicationConfig is right place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `@EnableWebMvc` and `<mvc:annotation-driven />` have the same purpose, enabling support for `@Controller` with `@RequestMapping`. They aren't complementary either use Java based config or xml, mixing them will not work.

The `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` or actually the `WebMvcConfigurer` is only designed and detected when using `@EnableWebMvc` not when using `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

When trying to enable/use them both you will run into issues with duplicate comopnents registered (like the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and such).

Comment: ok thanks. Is there any repercussions of removing `<mvc:annotation-driven />` . what is the general practice.. where can I read more about the topic.

Comment: Not if you enable `@EnableWebMvc`. IMHO the latter is easier to configure then xml but that is personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

`@EnableWebMvc` and `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` are the same thing for activating `@controller` and so on.

are you sure both xml and config files are loaded at load time?

maybe in your xml file address to the controller base package is wrong or something like that. try adding controller class as a bean and see if it is working

Comment: @M.Deinum: wow, my answer is revised. it's university all over again :-). thanks. it was and causing the problem, right?